# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderMenu' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to create a dynamic menu according to the json like this:

```
[
  {
    "teamId": "10000",
    "teamName": "笑傲江湖",
    "superTeamId": "",
    "createTime": "2017-06-25T06:07:45.000Z",
    "createUserId": null
  },
  {
    "teamId": "10001",
    "teamName": "计算机系",
    "superTeamId": "10000",
    "createTime": "2017-06-25T06:07:45.000Z",
    "createUserId": null
  },
  {
    "teamId": "10002",
    "teamName": "电子系",
    "superTeamId": "10000",
    "createTime": "2017-06-25T06:07:45.000Z",
    "createUserId": null
  },
  {
    "teamId": "10003",
    "teamName": "中文系",
    "superTeamId": "10000",
    "createTime": "2017-06-25T06:07:45.000Z",
    "createUserId": null
  },
  {
    "teamId": "10004",
    "teamName": "外文系",
    "superTeamId": "10000",
    "createTime": "2017-06-25T06:07:45.000Z",
    "createUserId": null
  },
  {
    "teamId": "10005",
    "teamName": "化学系",
    "superTeamId": "10000",
    "createTime": "2017-06-25T06:07:45.000Z",
    "createUserId": null
  }
]
```

**React code**

```js
renderMenu(team){
      //recursive rendering
      if(team.subcats && team.subcats.length){
        return (
          <SubMenu key={team.teamId} title = {team.teamName} >
            {team.subcats.map(this.renderMenu)}
          </SubMenu>
        );
      }else{
        return (
          <Menu.Item key={team.teamId}>
            {team.teamName}
          </Menu.Item>
        );
      }

  }
  render(){ 
    let  {teams} = this.props;
    teams.forEach(e => e.subcats=teams.filter(el=>el.superTeamId==e.teamId));
    teams =teams.filter(e=>e.superTeamId=='');
    return(
      <Menu mode="inline"    style={{ height: '100%' }}  >
      {teams.map(this.renderMenu)}
      </Menu>
    )
  }
```

when the code run,it show an err:

*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderMenu' of undefined*

Can any one help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding onClick for each Component in a .map() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799709/binding-onclick-for-each-component-in-a-map-function)

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
{team.subcats.map(this.renderMenu)}
```

tries to access context in this, but your function is not binded to the "this" you want. Try changing the following function:

```
renderMenu(team){
      //recursive rendering
      if(team.subcats && team.subcats.length){
        return (
          <SubMenu key={team.teamId} title = {team.teamName} >
            {team.subcats.map(this.renderMenu)}
          </SubMenu>
        );
      }else{
        return (
          <Menu.Item key={team.teamId}>
            {team.teamName}
          </Menu.Item>
        );
      }

  }
```

to an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
renderMenu = (team) => {
      //recursive rendering
      if(team.subcats && team.subcats.length){
        return (
          <SubMenu key={team.teamId} title = {team.teamName} >
            {team.subcats.map(this.renderMenu)}
          </SubMenu>
        );
      }else{
        return (
          <Menu.Item key={team.teamId}>
            {team.teamName}
          </Menu.Item>
        );
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

For use `this` in `renderMenu`

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.renderMenu = this.renderMenu.bind(this);
}
```

Or arrow function, like @user340764 said.

Answer (score 0):

callback as parameter will miss this, you must should be bind before use it

Comment: Please expand your answer to be more useful. Add some code for example.

Answer (score 0):

like@Andrew@user340764, bind renderMenu with this(context) before use it, or you
can do like this

```
  render(){
    const that = this
    let  {teams} = this.props;
    teams.forEach(e => e.subcats=teams.filter(el=>el.superTeamId==e.teamId));
    teams =teams.filter(e=>e.superTeamId=='');
    return(
      <Menu mode="inline"    style={{ height: '100%' }}  >
      {teams.map(that.renderMenu)}
      </Menu>
    )
  }
```